# Python project menu always runs one function regardless of input

Tags: python, function, project

I'm learning Python and am struggling on making my menu option correlate to the proper function.

The program should display a list upon running with menu options to either login or register an account, and once a number is pressed it should execute the function.

Now my program mostly works, however no matter what option is chosen it automatically selects register and runs that function.

I'm sure I'm doing something entirely wrong but I would like to learn. I am seeking some tips or suggestions.

```
#Function for creating an account
def create():
    username = input("Please enter your desired username ")
    password = input("Please enter your desired password ")

    return username, password


#Function for login not built out yet
def login():
    username = create()
    password = create()
    print("What is your username?")


#Menu
ans = True
while ans:
    print ("""
    1. Create an account
    2. Login to an existing account
           """)

    ans=input("What would you like to do")
    if ans=="1":
        create()
    elif ans=="2":
        login()


    else:
        print("Not a vaild option")
```

Comment: The function **create** returns a Tuple of the two values (the name from the input calls). To use the two values you just assign them to names for example: `user_name, pass_word = create()`

Answer (score 1):

because you call the create function from the login function however you can use this code:

```
#Function for creating an account
def create():
    username = input("Please enter your desired username ")
    password = input("Please enter your desired password ")

    return username, password


#Function for login not built out yet
def login():
    username = input("Enter your username")
    password = input("Enter your password")
    #  login action

#Menu
ans = True
while ans:
    print ("""
    1. Create an account
    2. Login to an existing account
           """)
    ans=input("What would you like to do")
    if ans=="1":
        create()
    elif ans=="2":
        login()
    else:
        print("Not a vaild option")
```

Comment: Okay i see my error now, i guess im confused then on how to pass the entered username and password into my login function. Do you by chance know how that would be done?

Comment: its a cli script it depends on what do you want, if you have some features in mind i can help you out